# Duplex printing options using lp or lpr

Tags: printing, cups, lp

The default options for a Brother MFC-9340CDW printer, are reportedly (e.g. querried via `lpoptions -l`) set to:

```
PageSize/Media Size: *A4 Letter Legal Executive A5 A6 B5 JISB5 JISB6 EnvDL EnvC5 Env10 EnvMonarch Br3x5 FanFoldGermanLegal EnvPRC5Rotated Postcard EnvYou4 EnvChou3 210x270mm 195x270mm 184x260mm 197x273mm
BRDuplex/Two-Sided: DuplexTumble *DuplexNoTumble None
BRInputSlot/Paper Source: AutoSelect *Tray1 Manual
BRResolution/Print Quality: 600dpi *600x2400dpi
BRMonoColor/Color / Mono: Auto FullColor *Mono
BRMediaType/Media Type: *Plain Thin Thick Thicker BOND Env EnvThick EnvThin Recycled Label Glossy PostCard
BRColorMatching/Color Mode: *Normal Vivid None
BRGray/Improve Gray Color: OFF *ON
BREnhanceBlkPrt/Enhance Black Printing: OFF *ON
BRTonerSaveMode/Toner Save Mode: OFF *ON
BRImproveOutput/Improve Print Output: OFF *BRLessPaperCurl BRFixIntensity
BRSkipBlank/Skip Blank Page: *OFF ON
BRBrightness/Brightness: -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
BRContrast/Contrast: -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
BRRed/Red: -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
BRGreen/Green: -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
BRBlue/Blue: -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
BRSaturation/Saturation: -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Though a simple `lp`(`r`) command should make use of the default options, duplex printing does not work as expected, e.g., the option `*DuplexNoTumble` should result in a double sided print of the document so as to turn the paper along its long edge. The result, however, for a PDF document, is a `DuplexTumble` one!

Even manually setting the options of interest in the command line directly does not complete as expected, e.g.

```
lp -o PageSize=A4 -o BRDuplex=DuplexNoTumble -o BRInputSlot=Tray1 -o BRResolution=600dpi -o BRMonoColor=Auto -o BRMediaType=Plain -o BRColorMatching=Normal -o BRTonerSaveMode=ON -o BRImproveOutput=BRLessPaperCurl SomeDocument.pdf
```

prints a Short-Edge binded print-out.

Strangely, setting the `BRDuplex` to `None`, gives the same Short-Edge Binding. There must be some configuration option set to "Short-Edge Binding" somwhere that overrides the `lpoptions`.

**Where (else) are Duplex printing related options set?**

---

Details

- Printer: Model Name Brother **MFC-9340CDW**, Main Firmware Version **K**, Sub1 Firmware Version **1.02**, Sub2 Firmware Version **F1309271100**
- OS: Funtoo
- Printer Driver Installed via https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/brother-overlay
- The `http://localhost:631/printers/Brother_MFC-9340CDW` reports, however:

  - Driver:    Brother MFC-9340CDW CUPS (color, 2-sided printing)
  - Connection:    lpd://192.168.10.6/BINARY_P1
  - Defaults:  job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=one-sided
- Section of interest in the file `Brother_MFC-9340CDW.ppd`:

> ```
> *%=== BRDuplex ================================
> *OpenUI *BRDuplex/Two-Sided: PickOne
> *OrderDependency: 25 AnySetup *BRDuplex
> *DefaultBRDuplex: DuplexNoTumble
> *BRDuplex DuplexTumble/Short-Edge Binding: "          "
> *BRDuplex DuplexNoTumble/Long-Edge Binding: "          "
> *BRDuplex None/Off: "          "
> *CloseUI: *BRDuplex
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right place to set options for the (/this) printer, is in `/opt/brother/Printers/mfc9340cdw/inf/`**`brmfc9340cdwrc`**. The *problem* of always resulting in a *DuplexTumble* printing, was forced by the respective code-line (`BRDuplex=DuplexTumble`) in this configurations file.

Setting the option in question to `BRDuplex=DuplexNoTumble`, and restarting the **cupsd** service (in my case, using `rc-service cupsd restart` for OpenRC) results in double-sided prints binded along a document's long-edge.

---

*I came up to check for a file named like **br(model name)rc** only after reading this section of a relevant Ubuntu-Wiki page:* http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Brother/Drucker#Problembehebung

Comment: Anyhow, I still can't find a way to let the options `-o BRDuplex=DuplexTumble` or `-o BRDuplex=DuplexNoTumble` have an effect when fed from the command line! The only way to go seems to be from inside the *brmfc9340cdwrc* file.

Comment: (I realize this is from 3 years ago): You could also try the normal CUPS option `-o sides=two-sided-long-edge`. That works with my HLL2380DW (regardless of the rc file saying single-sided).

Comment: The printer still exists, I still use the same OS and setup. The printer is, though, far away at the moment :-). Thank you.

Comment: @derobert I realize this is from 6 years ago, but your solution seems to work for me, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Brother QL-720NW label printer and I had the setup `lpr` & `cups` using the rpm packaged drivers from Brother (I'm using Centos 7 64bit). However, each label resulted in a 2nd blank label because cups thought the device was double sided. Using the above answer I was able try to add a new line to `/opt/brother/PTouch/ql720nw/inf/brql820nwrc` so that the file ended with the line:

```
BRDuplex=OFF
```

I then issued a:

```
systemctl restart cups.service
```

and the problem has been fixed (at least until that file ever gets updated etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a network connected printer on ubuntu 20.04.

The problem was that I had setup the network printer manually and whenever the system booted the network printer was **re**-discovered and added again, so effectively I had two instances (probably with different drivers) pointing to the same printer.

- When printing through the print dialog (GUI) , the default selected printer was the one I had setup manually with duplex on.
- When printing through cmdline `lp filename.pdf` the printer defaulted to the automatically rediscovered printer where duplex was not configured.

  - `lpoptions -l` reported that duplex was configured
  - Manually specifying this option did not work either *(probably the wrong option name or since "duplex installed" needs to be set first... don't know, didn't manage to get it to work)*

**My Solution**

- I removed the network autodiscovery as follows:

1. `sudo vi /etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf`
2. Search for the line of interest <kbd>/</kbd> `BrowseRemoteProtocols`
3. commented out the original setting and set it to none

```
# Which protocols will we use to discover printers on the network?
# Can use DNSSD and/or CUPS and/or LDAP, or 'none' for neither.

# BrowseRemoteProtocols dnssd cups
BrowseRemoteProtocols none
```

4. Saved and quit <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> `wq`
5. Restarted the service: `service cups-browsed restart`
6. Removed the printer and Manually added it again, set to default and Success!

I also found very usefull the following :  http://localhost:631/help/options.html